# wait for complete response from async ajax tfrom api call

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asynchronous, callback

I have this ajax call in vanilla javascript which calls an api asynchronously and need to cache the response in localstorage. Here is my code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhttp.responseText);
                localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "/api/orgData", true);
        xhttp.send();
```

Problem is what I see for the value of Data in the local storage is [object object] although console.log prints the value of xhttp.responseText. I guess the issue has do with api response is not complete yet (not sure why this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 is not helping). Could you please help to solve this issue so that it caches the data into local storage when the result is fully back from api. Also I am making this call in head of my html and I can only use vanilla javascript no jquery or other things. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove json.parse and store the responseText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have here is that [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) only stores strings, it doesn't store objects. So in this precise case what you have is the result of applying `toString` on your object.

A solution would be to store the JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem('Data', xhttp.responseText);
```

And when you need the value you do

```
var thing = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
```

Be careful though that localStorage is limited in size, you'd better store just the important values.